# extracting dmg file in Linux

Tags: linux, dmg-image

Is there a way to extract this DMG file?

```
$ file obs-mac-26.0.2.dmg 
obs-mac-26.0.2.dmg: lzfse encoded, lzvn compressed
```

Unfortunately, 7zip raised an error.

```
$ 7za x obs-mac-26.0.2.dmg
7-Zip (a) [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       L 640  @ 2.13GHz (20655),ASM,AES-NI)
Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 109406941 bytes (105 MiB)
Extracting archive: obs-mac-26.0.2.dmg
ERROR: obs-mac-26.0.2.dmg
Can not open the file as archive
Can't open as archive: 1
Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Your 7-Zip reports its version as 16.02 (dated on 2016-05-21).

According to the [history of the 7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/history.txt) you need the version 18.01 (dated on 2018-01-28):

> 18.01        2018-01-28
>
> - 7-Zip now can unpack DMG archives that use LZFSE compression method.
> - […]

or newer. Upgrade.

Comment: Thanks. 7-Zip 19 on Windows can open the file.
I tried to build 7zDec from the source code of 7-Zip 19.00 but it does not work. Maybe not all the features are supported for Linux.